# Shell or Python Script to change the values of json file

Tags: python, shell

I have a following Json file controller.txt which i need for my daily work

```
{
    "user": "dexter",
    "Issue": "**MUX-4190**",
    "start_date": "**2018-01-01**",
    "end_date": "**2018-12-30**",
    "Demo_nos": [**111**],
    "service_names": [
             "**Demo1.service.test**",
             "**Demo2.service.test**", 
             "**Demo3.service.test**",
             "**Demo4.service.test**",
             "**Demo5.service.tes**t"
        ]
}
```

So i always need to change the below highlighted entries in the json file,
is there any way(using shell/python) that i can type this values in and these fields keep populating accordingly instead manually editing the control.txt json file everytime???

- Issue
- start date
- end date
- Demo_nos
- Service names

Comment: i hope you got my question? i want to take these values as user input, i am trying the below code provided by @Ravi but there is some issue with that..The json file variables remain same only the value is what i want as dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

with open('your_file.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data['Issue'] = 'Example' # Update your value
    data['start date'] = 'Your date'
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: its working but instead of making changes to an existing entries it is updating the same data twice, i mean it creates a second block with the info i update together with the previous block

Comment: Be sure you `seek()` to the beginning of the file before doing a `truncate()` if the goal is to rewrite from the beginning, and to do the write only *after* the truncate.

Comment: Also, note that it's dangerous to update files in-place like this at all; much safer to write a new/temporary file, and rename it over the original when done. That way a crash at the wrong time doesn't leave your file empty, or a program reading it while the update is still ongoing doesn't see it as corrupt.